# c# - UDP Socket BeginReceive() (Find IpAddress)

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets, udp

I'm trying to receive UDP Packets on this port: 8070

I have a program for sending UDP packets and I will receive data in another program (Receiver) but I can't find the sender IP address!
i'm using socket and my code is this:

```
    Socket UdpListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8070);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1000];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UdpListener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.PacketInformation, true);
        UdpListener.Bind(ipep);


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UdpListener.BeginReceive(buf, 0, buf.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnRecv), UdpListener);


    }

    private void OnRecv(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        UdpListener.EndReceive(ar);

        UdpListener.BeginReceive(buf, 0, buf.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnRecv), UdpListener);
    }
```

I Will Receive Data but how can I find Sender IP Address?

i tried this:

```
Socket s = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        MessageBox.Show(s.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
```

but I get this Error:

```
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UdpListener.BeginReceiveFrom` instead of `UdpListener.BeginReceive` as it offers a reference to the sending endpoint.

Further information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for you answer, i see the link and change my code to MSDN example code, but i get following error on "s.connect(sender)": "The requested address is not valid in its context"